# Why the MetaFont in Miktex always run errors?

Tags: fonts, metafont

I am trying the codewords of MetaFont textbook of D. Knuth many times with cmd in Windows. No matter the example files such as io.mf or even simple commands such as \relax, the outcome of those running is always "Emergency stop" in the cmd black screen. I wonder why, and whether the use of "mf" had been forbidden?

Answer (score 3):

`io.mf` is really just a partial file intended to be included in a complete font however

```
mf io.mf bye
```

should include the file and then issue `bye` command to close metafont properly, leaving `io.2602gf` in the current directory.

Comment: Mr. Carlisle, thanks. I have found even the "Emergency stop" appeared, the io.2602gf still leaving.